# Laravel 5.6 Passport token in ajax

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I was writing below code in Token Guard before using Passport authentication.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:    "{!! route('ViewProfile') !!}?api_token={!! \Auth::user()->api_token !!}",
    cache:  false,
    async:  true,
    success: function(result) {

    },
    error: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Now, I am changing my code to adapt Laravel Passport authentication. I have no problem in creating the token and fetching it using below code.

```
$token = $UserData->createToken(env("Token_Source_Website"))->accessToken;
```

**Question:** I was searching for a tutorial about how to send the ajax request to get user details using this token? I meant, will I use something else instead of api_token = somevalue?

Comment: I want to retrieve the user details using the token through jquery ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be like below. Make sure there is space after Bearer in headers.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:    "{!! route('ViewProfile') !!}?api_token={!! \Auth::user()->api_token !!}",
    cache:  false,
    async:  true,
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')},
    success: function(result) {

    },
    error: function(result) {

    }
});
```

One can get the token through below code.

```
$token = $UserData->createToken(env("Token_Source_Website"))->accessToken;
```

Comment: the token will be encrypted??

Comment: The token is encrypted and received from the the create token function server side.

Comment: Hello Pankaj, How can I get this token? `localStorage.getItem('token')`

Comment: @BlueSuiter First, a key will have to be stored in a login page after authentication in success call back like this. `localStorage.setItem('token', "My Token");` and then you can access it as mentioned in answer.

Comment: @Okay thank you :). Are you familiar in mobile apps using Laravel?